# Why doesn't Vincent kill Annie first?

Tags: collateral

On rewatch, a friend noticed that Max picks up Vincent right as he drops off Annie - which is to say Vincent was already at the location for the first of his targets.

Why does he save her for last instead of killing her first?

And even if there's a reason for that, why does he go to her building first?

Answer (score 2):

He was likely researching the location she would be at. Note how he basically tests the key card he needs to enter then building and then leaves. He also cannot kill her there and then, it would be too much in the open. It would also trigger a much larger police action, unlike when he first kills a number of underworld-related characters.

---

Of course, from a story point of view, it happened like that so there would be a surprise later on in the movie when it turns out that his final target is the woman we met early on in the movie.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been a very bad move on Vincent's part to kill Annie very early into the evening (which is only a few minutes into the film), as police and witness presence in general would have been more intense as opposed to the early hours of the morning. Carrying out the hit then would be tantamount to suicide as the 911 switchboards would have been flooded with calls of people reporting an active shooting, triggering a much larger police action before he could get to the other hits, as BCdotWEB puts it. I would imagine that the cops would have been swarming the area very quickly if not a few minutes considering that the place Annie works at is a federal building.

As for your second question, I would assume that it would have something to do with doing some recon about the building so that he could get in and out as quickly as possible without anyone noticing.